# Dyadic squares and circle approximation.

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

First, let me briefly introduce dyadic squares:

A dyadic rational is a rational number $a = \frac{p}{2^k}, p\in \mathbb{Z}, k \in \mathbb{N}$. A dyadic interval is an interval $[a,b]$ with $a = \frac{p}{2^k},b = \frac{p+1}{2^k}$. One can easily verify that the length of the interval is fully determined by $k$. A dyadic square is the cartesian product of two dyadic intervals of same length. 2 different dyadic squares are either always intersecting, have a common vertex or are completely disjoint. For proof of the last statement, I reference [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4601778/real-analysis-dyadic-squares-and-rigorous-proof-writing/4601888#4601888) excellent answer.

Another exercise on dyadic squares that I'm struggling with:

> Given $\epsilon > 0$, show that the unit disc contains finitely many dyadic squares whose area exceeds $\pi  - \epsilon$ and which intersect each other only along their boundaries. b) Show that this also holds true in the case in which all dyadic squares are disjoint.

Here, my issue lies in the fact that I don't know where to begin.

**My reasoning steps thus far**

1. Initially, I didn't really know where to begin so I tried to dissect the problem. The phrasing reminded me remotely of sequence convergence, so I wrote down the definition of sequence convergence and "tweaked" it in a way such that it looks applicable to the question at hand: $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}: n \ge n_{0} \rightarrow |f(n) - \pi| < \epsilon$ for some function $f$.
2. Then I asked myself - does this make sense, and if yes why? I think it does, especially if one defines $f(n)$ as a function which maps the interval size (as determined by k) to the total area covered by the dyadic squares of that side length. For instance, for k = 0, 0 dyadic squares fit into the unit disc, hence $f(0) = 0$. To visualize I have added two drawings below:
   [image: k = 2][image: k = 1]

The first picture is a representation of all dyadic squares that fit into the unit disc with side length $k = 1 \rightarrow length = \frac{1}{2^1}$; the second picture represents all dyadic squares with side length $k = 2$. To save you the counting I just numbered the dyadic squares; the function $f$ that I have described before would give $f(1) = 1$ (as the squares are of size $\frac{1}{4}$ each, $f(2) = 2$ (square size $\frac{1}{16}$.

I noticed that the dyadic squares fill out the circle yet become smaller and smaller, so the limit of the function $f$ must be $\pi$.

**My questions and approaches**

**How can I find a formula for $f$?** I have tried some sample numbers but they become quite "crooked" quickly: $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2$,but  f(3) = 2.5625. I have looked at the integer sequence of dyadic squares that I would be considering for each $k$ (for k = 1 it is 4, for k = 2 it is 32, for k = 3 it is 164, for k = 4 it is 704, etc.) in the OEIS, and found only a reference to an academic paper I don't understand (topic: self-avoiding walks).

Another thing I have tried would involve showing convergence by showing whatever f would be, f must be bounded and is monotonically increasing (and hence converges). However, I don't want to use the monotone convergence theorem to show convergence as the book that I'm working with hasn't introduced it yet (also I don't know how I would approach the problem).

**A tentative solution**

A "sort of" solution that I came up with goes as follows:

Let $\epsilon$ be given. Suppose there were infinitely many dyadic squares fully included in the unit disc of size exceeding $\pi - \epsilon$, and suppose all these dyadic squares only intersected along their edges. Pick any such squares repeatedly until the sum of their areas is larger than $pi$ (this works and can be proven using Archimedean Principle but this is very simply so I will omit here). Then the area of the squares would exceed the area of the unit disc, contradicting the fact that they all are contained by the unit disc.

I am unsure about this solution in part because I don't know what the author means by the statement "finitely many dyadic squares whose area exceeds $\pi - \epsilon$. **Does he mean there are finitely many which together sum up to $\pi - \epsilon$ or does he mean that there are finitely many with each one having a size larger than $\pi - \epsilon$? Is my approach even logically sound? If it is not, why not?**

I also took a look at part b), and it is even more overwhelming. The logic of my proof would apply there too, which is another reason why I am suspicious of that proof. Any hints for part b) would be greatly appreciated here as well.

Comment: By the definition you gave for a "dyadic interval", the maximum possible length is $\frac 1{2^0} =1$. So the maximum area of dyadic square is $1$. The author cannot mean that each square has area $\ge \pi - \epsilon$. Thus it must mean the total area covered by all the squares is $\ge \pi - \epsilon$. (BTW - "$k$" is not a "length". Please stop calling it that. You only confuse yourself and your audience when you do. The length of a dyadic interval for a particular value of $k$ is $\frac 1{2^k}$.)

Comment: For each $k$, you can divide $[-1,1]^2$ into $4^{k+1}$ dyadic squares of sidelength $2^{-k}$, area $4^{-k}$. These can be placed into three groups: Those inside the unit circle, those outside the unit circle, and those that intersect the unit circle. Try to show that there are *at most* $8\cdot 2^k$ squares in the last group (note that this is the perimeter of $[-1,1]^2$ divided by the sidelength of the dyadic squares). Once you have shown that, note that the total area of that group goes to $0$ as $k$ increases.

Comment: As for part (b), solve (a) first. then divide the dyadic squares in it into checkerboards of smaller such squares, and remove the lowest row and left column for each of those checkerboards. Show that by choosing the new $k$ small enough, you can make the sum of the removed square areas $\to 0$ as well.